# How to display a control over app bar in WP8 app?

Tags: windows-phone, position, controls, popupmenu, application-bar

Working on a popup menu displayed when an app bar icon button is clicked (similar to the Respond button submenu in the standard Email WP app). How can I position a control like StackPanel over the app bar when the app bar is visible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Windows Phone Application Bar is a system control, so it is created by system and appears "on" your application. You can try to use [third-party control](http://mobile.dzone.com/articles/how-build-custom-application) for Application Bar or try to calculate position for your StackPanel manually dependent on screen size and orientation.